# Block binding in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binding

I am confused by the definition of block binding in ruby. Here are two samples:

```
def redfine_a(&block)
  a = 2
  puts eval("a", block.binding)
  block.call
end
a = "hello"
puts redfine_a {a}
```

This one could run with the expected result, while the second one:

```
def redefine_a(&block)
  a= 2
  puts eval("a", block.binding)
  block.call
end

puts redefine_a{a= "hello"}
```

will complain:

```
undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object (NameError)
```

After I removed the `puts eval("a", block.binding)`, my code run:

```
def redefine_a(&block)
  a= 2
  block.call
end

puts redefine_a{a= "hello"}
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 9):

`block.binding` is the environment in which the block is defined, before it runs.

Answer (score 3):

In your code the context where the block is defined is the `main` object, so the line `eval("a", block.binding)` will return the value of `a` in `main`. In your first example `a` is defined in `main` and so the code runs, in the second example there is no `a` in main and so the error.

In both cases though, the `a=2` in your `redefine_a` method can have no effect.